# Loop through form and only add data to array if it isn't there

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a regex that loops through data like the following

```
23:10:54 User Name 1 has looted 598 x Dark Ochre
23:13:58 UserName 2 has looted 947 x Obsidian Ochre
22:55:29 User Name3 has looted 1509 x Onyx Ochre
22:55:29 User Name3 has looted 3 x Obsidian Ochre
```

The regex (below) correctly parses the data into the value `$value['userName'];`

```
$re = '/^(?<timeMined>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) # timeMined 
     \s+
     (?<userName>[\w\s]+)        # user name
     \s+(?:has\s+looted)\s+    # garbage text between name and amount
     (?<amount>\d+)              # amount
     \s+x\s+                     # multiplication symbol
     (?<item>.*?)\s*$            # item name (to end of line)
   /xmu';
preg_match_all($re, $sample, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

In the data set below, there are 3 distinct user names. I am attempting to loop through the data and add a user name to an array if it doesn't already exist. This is what I currently have. However, I only get 1 result, User Name3. I'm confused as to where the issue lies here.

```
foreach ($matches as $value){
  $userName = $value['userName'];
  echo $userName."<BR>";
  $userNameArray = array();
  if (in_array($userName, $userNameArray)){
  }
  else {
    array_push($userNameArray, $userName);
  }
}
echo "<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>";
foreach ($userNameArray as $value){
  echo $value."<BR>";
}
```

This code results in the following. The top part is accurate, the bottom however, is missing two user names

```
User Name 1
UserName 2
User Name3
User Name3






User Name3
```

Comment: Why the empty `if` condition? Why not `if (!in_array($userName, $userNameArray)){`. Note the `!` which `NOT`s the test.

Comment: mostly because i know it will work. I always get a little hesitant throwing in an exclamation point. For me, that's always one more moving part to break

Comment: What about anyone who comes after you? You should aim to make your code re-usable, easy to read, and adjust your own quirks accordingly. Boolean algebra has been around a lot longer than you... a lot longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you delete your array in the for loop in each iteration ;)

```
foreach ($matches as $value){
  $userName = $value['userName'];
  echo $userName."<BR>";
  $userNameArray = array(); // resetting the array each time...
  if (in_array($userName, $userNameArray)){
  }
  else {
    array_push($userNameArray, $userName);
  }
}
```

Comment: sometimes i hate myself. will green mark as soon as it lets me

Comment: @mhopkins321 BTW: You could make your code look nicer by replacing   if (in_array($userName, $userNameArray)){
  }
  else {
    array_push($userNameArray, $userName);
  }
with   if (!in_array($userName, $userNameArray)){
    array_push($userNameArray, $userName);
  }